# Update several columns in several rows from 1 row in same table

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

We have a table with several fields, like 300+. the structure is like this:
storenum, Monval1, Monval2... Monval45, Monval46... Tuesval1, Tuesval2 and so on.  basically for values 1 thru 53 there is a version for each day of the week so 53 fields * 7 days plus a few other random fields.

i need to update stores 3 thru 285 with data from store 1.  what i tried:

```
Update (Select MonVal1... SunVal53 from table1 
 where storenum in (3, 4,...284,285)) as Dest
From (Select MonVal1... SunVal53 from table1 
 where storenum =1) as Source
```

but its a nogo.

can what i'm trying to do even be done?

Comment: normalization nightmare.

Comment: i didn't design the db, i just work here, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update table1 set
    MonVal1    = origin.MonVal1, 
    /* the orher fields here */
    SunVal53   = origin.SunVal53
from table1
inner join table1 as origin on origin.storenum = 1
where table1.storenum in (3, 4,...284,285)
```

Comment: yeah, this is what i was hoping to avoid.  i really didn't want to have to list all the this = that stuff, but i guess if i have to, that's what Alt+Shift is for right?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can write a super long update statement of this pattern:

```
UPDATE badly_normalized_table
SET monval1 =   ( SELECT monval1 FROM badly_normalized_table WHERE ... )
WHERE pk = the_pk_you_want_to_upate
```

Comment: are you saying to then copy this whole thing and paste it for every field? or i could just copy the set line but then its doing a select for every field.  thanks.